# Java reflexão verificador de valores

Tags: java, reflexão

Estou tentando usar Reflection e Recursividade para capturar valores.

Por exemplo:

```
public class Endereco{
       String rua;
       Integer numero;
}
public class Cachorro{
       String nome;
       Integer idade;
}
public class Pessoa{ 
       String nome;
       Cachorro cachorro;
       List<Endereco> endereco;
}
```

Eu crio uma `List<Pessoa>` e populo ela, só que estou tentando percorrer essas pessoas e contar seus atributos nulos e não nulos. 
Por exemplo: eu tenho uma lista com 5 Pessoas e quero verificar se no atributo nome, cachorro(dentro da classe cachorro), ou qualquer outro é diferente de `null` e contar isso. Preciso que seja recursivo, mas não consegui fazer.

Desculpe se não me expressei direito.

Comment: Que código com reflexão você já tentou fazer? Porque não conseguiu? O que deu errado?

Comment: Poste o código que você usou.

Comment: Eu primeiramente passo para um método que contém um For e ele percorre minha lista, após isso, pego todos os objetos dentro de cada objeto Pessoa, ou seja, nome, lista de endereços, cachorro. Mas, eu não consigo entender como eu poderia entrar em cada atributo e contar especificamente o atributo. Exemplo: getNome(), verifica se nessas 5 pessoas se o nome é nulo ou não e conta, próximo, Cachorro, entra no objeto Cachorro pega todos  os objetos dentro desse Cachorro e conta novamente cada atributo, assim até acabar as minhas classes.

Comment: Poste o seu código na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Todas as classes que implementarem a interface AtributoContavel os seus atributos poderão ser contados.

```
public interface AtributoContavel {
 public int getQuantidadeAtributosNulos();
 public int getQuantidadeAtributosNaoNulos();
```

}

A classe App é a classe principal que chamará recursivamente os métodos de cálculo de atributos nulos e não nulos e ao final retorna o resultado.

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<AtributoContavel> pessoas = inicializar();
    System.out.println("Quantidade de Atributos Nulos = " + calcularAtributosNulos(pessoas,0,0));
    System.out.println("Quantidade de Atributos Nao Nulos = " + calcularAtributosNaoNulos(pessoas,0,0));

}

public static List<AtributoContavel> inicializar() {

    List<Endereco> enderecos = new ArrayList<>();
    enderecos.add(new Endereco("Rua Teste ", 13));
    enderecos.add(new Endereco("Rua Teste 2", 14));

    List<AtributoContavel> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();
    Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Saulo", null, null);
    Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("Thiago", new Cachorro("Jack", 2),null);
    Pessoa p3 = new Pessoa("Saulo", new Cachorro("Tob", 2), enderecos );

    pessoas.add(p1);
    pessoas.add(p2);
    pessoas.add(p3);

    return pessoas;
}

public static int calcularAtributosNulos(List<AtributoContavel> pessoas, int posicao, int total) {
    total+=pessoas.get(posicao).getQuantidadeAtributosNulos();
    posicao++;
    if(pessoas.size() == posicao)
        return total;
    return calcularAtributosNulos(pessoas, posicao, total);
}


public static int calcularAtributosNaoNulos(List<AtributoContavel> pessoas, int posicao, int total) {
    total+=pessoas.get(posicao).getQuantidadeAtributosNaoNulos();
    posicao++;
    if(pessoas.size() == posicao) 
        return total;
    return calcularAtributosNaoNulos(pessoas, posicao, total);
}
```

As demais classes só implementam a interface AtributoContavel e tem suas respectivas implementacões dos métodos abstratos

```
public class Endereco implements AtributoContavel {
private String rua;
private Integer numero;

Endereco(String rua, Integer numero){
    this.rua = rua;
    this.numero = numero;
}

@Override
public int getQuantidadeAtributosNulos() {
    int qtdAtributosNulos = 0;
    if(this.rua == null)  qtdAtributosNulos++;
    if(this.numero == null) qtdAtributosNulos++;
    return  qtdAtributosNulos++;
}

public int getQuantidadeAtributosNaoNulos() {
    int qtdAtributosNaoNulos = 0;
    if(this.rua != null)  qtdAtributosNaoNulos++;
    if(this.numero != null) qtdAtributosNaoNulos++;
    return  qtdAtributosNaoNulos++;
}}





public class Cachorro implements AtributoContavel {
private String nome;
private Integer idade;

Cachorro(String nome, Integer idade){
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
}

@Override
public int getQuantidadeAtributosNulos() {
    int qtdAtributosNulos = 0;
    if(this.nome == null)  qtdAtributosNulos++;
    if(this.idade == null) qtdAtributosNulos++;
    return  qtdAtributosNulos++;
}

public int getQuantidadeAtributosNaoNulos() {
    int qtdAtributosNaoNulos = 0;
    if(this.nome != null)  qtdAtributosNaoNulos++;
    if(this.idade != null) qtdAtributosNaoNulos++;
    return  qtdAtributosNaoNulos++;
}
```

}

```
public class Pessoa implements AtributoContavel {
private String nome;
private Cachorro cachorro;
private List<Endereco> enderecos;

Pessoa(String nome, Cachorro cachorro, List<Endereco> enderecos){
    this.nome = nome;
    this.cachorro = cachorro;
    this.enderecos = enderecos;
}

@Override
public int getQuantidadeAtributosNulos() {
    int qtdAtributosNulos = 0;
    if(this.nome == null)  qtdAtributosNulos++;

    if(this.cachorro == null)
         qtdAtributosNulos++;
    else
        qtdAtributosNulos += this.cachorro.getQuantidadeAtributosNulos();

    if(this.enderecos == null) {
        qtdAtributosNulos++;
    }
    else {
        for (Endereco endereco : enderecos) {
            if(endereco == null)
                 qtdAtributosNulos++;
            else
                qtdAtributosNulos+=endereco.getQuantidadeAtributosNulos();
        }
    }
    return  qtdAtributosNulos++;
}

@Override
public int getQuantidadeAtributosNaoNulos() {
    int qtdAtributosNaoNulos = 0;
    if(this.nome != null)  qtdAtributosNaoNulos++;

    if(this.cachorro != null)
        qtdAtributosNaoNulos += this.cachorro.getQuantidadeAtributosNaoNulos();

    if(this.enderecos != null) {
        for (Endereco endereco : enderecos) {
            if(endereco != null)
                qtdAtributosNaoNulos+=endereco.getQuantidadeAtributosNaoNulos();
        }
    }
    return  qtdAtributosNaoNulos++;
}}
```